# passing parameters to RIA service from extjs with json end point

Tags: extjs4, ria

I am trying to communicate with RIA service from extjs using POST for getting response with following code.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                        model: 'RootResults',
                        proxy: {
                            type: 'ajax',
                            actionMethods: 'POST',
                            url: 'MyService.svc/JSON/GetRes',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-type': 'application/json' 
                            },
                            reader: {
                                type: 'json',
                                root: 'GetResResult.RootResults',
                                totalProperty: 'GetResResult.TotalCount'
                            }
                            , pageParam: undefined,
                            startParam: undefined,
                            limitParam: undefined

                            , success: function (response) {
                                alert(response);

                            }

                        }
                    });

     var operation = new Ext.data.Operation({
          FId: 1,
          SId: 0
      });

 store.load({ params: Ext.encode(operation) });
```

i can access it with get.
when i am trying with POST, it returning error - "405 Method Not Allowed".
what to do to make it POST enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i asked this question, i am bit confused with POST communication between extjs and RIA services.

I solved this with the help of following article
http://www.joseph-connolly.com/blog/post/WCF-RIA-Services-jQuery-and-JSON-endpoint-Part-2.aspx

For accessing WCF RIA Services from jquery or extjs, actually we need to create changeset for CUD(Create-Update-Delete) operations and All of the operations use JSON/SubmitChanges.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that on the server end you need to add `HasSideEffects` to your method declaration ():

```
[Invoke(HasSideEffects = true)]
public GetPages(...)
{

}
```